# How to add Ajax request in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How to execute ajax request in zend framework 2?
I am beginner specially for zend framework 2. so i am not sure how to disabled layout... for my json response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you want to execute ajax request in zf2.

```
 $viewModel = new ViewModel();

 $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
 return $viewModel;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your ajax url must be like this `baseurl+'/yourcontroller/ajax'`

And in your ajax Action

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
      $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
      $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(); //ajax dont wants a view

     //you can access your params like this

     echo $this->_helper->getParam('paramname');exit;

}
```